# How to connect multiple clients simultaneously to a websockets server that uses NATS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio, nats.io

Does anyone know why only one client is able to connect at the same time to a websockets server that uses NATS? Here is my code:

**subscribehandlernats.py**

```py
import asyncio
import signal
from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS


class SubscribeHandler:
    subject_list = []

    def __init__(self, subject_list, subscribe_handler):
        self.subject_list = subject_list
        self.subscribe_handler = subscribe_handler

    async def run(self, loop):
        nc = NATS()

        try:
            await nc.connect("nats://localhost:4222")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        print(f"Connected to NATS at {nc.connected_url.netloc}...")

        def signal_handler():
            if nc.is_closed:
                return
            print("Disconnecting...")
            loop.create_task(nc.close())

        for sig in ('SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'):
            loop.add_signal_handler(getattr(signal, sig), signal_handler)

        for subject in self.subject_list:
            await nc.subscribe(subject, cb=self.subscribe_handler)
            print("Subscribed to:", subject)

        print("Awaiting...")

    def execute(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(self.run(loop=loop))
        try:
            loop.run_forever()
        finally:
            loop.close()
```

**server.py**

```py
import asyncio
import websockets
from subscribehandlernats import SubscribeHandler
import nest_asyncio


async def hello(websocket):
    async def subscribe_handler(msg):
        subject = msg.subject
        reply = msg.reply
        data = msg.data.decode()
        print("Received a message on '{subject} {reply}': {data}".format(
             subject=subject, reply=reply, data=data))
        await websocket.send("Received a message on '{subject} {reply}': {data}".format(
            subject=subject, reply=reply, data=data))

    s = SubscribeHandler(["hello.world"], subscribe_handler)
    s.execute()


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765, ping_interval=None):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nest_asyncio.apply()
    asyncio.run(main())
```

**client.py**

```py
import websockets


async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8765"
    async with websockets.connect(uri, ping_interval=None) as websocket:
        while True:
            greeting = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"<<< {greeting}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(hello())
```

If I first run **server.py** (websockets server) and then **client.py** and publish some messages:

```
~$ nats pub hello.world "Hello World America!"
17:22:20 Published 20 bytes to "hello.world"
~$ nats pub hello.world "Hello World Europe!"
17:22:34 Published 19 bytes to "hello.world"
```

They are received by the websockets server:

```
/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/bin/python /home/ubuntuuser/test/server.py 
Connected to NATS at localhost:4222...
Subscribed to: hello.world
Awaiting...
Received a message on 'hello.world ': Hello World America!
Received a message on 'hello.world ': Hello World Europe!
```

Which sends them to the connected client:

```
/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/bin/python /home/ubuntuuser/test/client.py 
<<< Received a message on 'hello.world ': Hello World America!
<<< Received a message on 'hello.world ': Hello World Europe!
```

But, if I start a second client (client2.py with the same code as in client.py), I get this error:

```
/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/bin/python /home/ubuntuuser/test/client2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 655, in __await_impl_timeout__
    return await self.__await_impl__()
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 662, in __await_impl__
    await protocol.handshake(
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 323, in handshake
    status_code, response_headers = await self.read_http_response()
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 139, in read_http_response
    status_code, reason, headers = await read_response(self.reader)
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/http.py", line 120, in read_response
    status_line = await read_line(stream)
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/http.py", line 194, in read_line
    line = await stream.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/streams.py", line 525, in readline
    line = await self.readuntil(sep)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/streams.py", line 617, in readuntil
    await self._wait_for_data('readuntil')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/streams.py", line 502, in _wait_for_data
    await self._waiter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/client2.py", line 16, in 
    asyncio.run(hello())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/client2.py", line 9, in hello
    async with websockets.connect(uri, ping_interval=None) as websocket:
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 637, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 654, in __await_impl_timeout__
    async with asyncio_timeout(self.open_timeout):
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/async_timeout.py", line 169, in __aexit__
    self._do_exit(exc_type)
  File "/home/ubuntuuser/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/async_timeout.py", line 252, in _do_exit
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What code changes do I have to make in order to connect more than one client simultaneously to the websockets server? I have read this section in the websockets FAQ but I have not been able to solve the issue so far:

https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/asyncio.html

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance